# HTTP POST to Rails 3 using C#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, http, post

I'm attempting to send an HTTP POST to a Rails 3 Application. Currently all I want to do is login from the C# client and receive a response in either XML or JSON.

Here is the controller code, I am using the Sorcery gem for the login.

```
class ClientSessionsController < ApplicationController

skip_before_filter :require_login, :except => [:create]

def create
   if @user = login(params[:username],params[:password])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.xml { render :xml => @user }
       format.json { render :json => @user }
     end
   else
     respond_to do |format|
       format.xml { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => 400  }
       format.json { render :json => @users.errors, :status => 400 }
     end
   end
end
```

Initially I used the WebClient.UploadValues, however you cannot appear to be able to set the header for this request. So I tried using the WebRequest class in .NET.

I followed the example here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1700/entry-3583-how-to-get-a-c%23-app-to-upload-to-rails-respond-to-do-format-xml/

However I simply received a 500 response.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was receiving a 500 response due to a rouge require_login which I had in application.html.erb.

So my problem was nothing to do with the C#, and the code posted on the link above works perfectly if anyone else is having trouble doing something similar.